# Images not showing in Form Recognizer Label Editor

Tags: forms, azure-form-recognizer

I have created a Form Recognizer Service using the Quick Start instructions and created the connection and project in the label editor without errors. The SAS URI is valid and the Form Recognizer key and end point are valid. I have validated the container location by entering the URL with a file name in a browser and viewing them. According to the Instructions in Quick Start and instructions provided by Microsoft and others my setup is complete and correct. When the project is saved the image files are supposed to appear in the label editor and they do not. I have created numerous projects and connections with the same result. I believe the key items are the Form Recognizer end point and key, the SAS URI, and the source (the form to be   recognized) location. Everything else is text of my choosing. Can you provide any insights into what I have missed?    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your data flat on the container or in a folder ? If in a folder please add the folder name to the folder path in the project setting.
If it is not in a folder can you please try copying it into a folder and see if it works.

Comment: The data is in the container, no folders. The files are the samples provided by Quick Start, invoice_1.pdf through invoice_5,pdf. I have found that the files appear in layout analyze and prebuilt analyze individually but not in tags editor.

Comment: Did you enable CORs on the container ? Can you please try putting the the files under a folder and see if that solves the issue. Feel free to contact support also or Form Recognizer Contact Us <formrecog_contact@microsoft.com>

Comment: You should remove PII and your folder name from here. Please contact Form Recognizer Contact Us <formrecog_contact@microsoft.com> or open an Azure support ticket and we will try to assist.